# Consequence of inequality

Tags: analysis

My question:

> Let $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ bounded. For all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a constant $C(\varepsilon)>0$ such that
> $$
> \label{lemma_gagliardo_nirenberg_2}
>   \|\varphi\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2
>   \le \varepsilon \|\nabla \varphi\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + C(\varepsilon) \|\varphi\|_{L^1(\Omega)}^2 \quad\text{ for all }\varphi \in W^{1,2}(\Omega).
> $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Gagliardo-Nirenberg it holds that
$$
\|u\|^2_{L^2} \leq C_1 \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^{2n/(n+2)} \|u\|_{L^1}^{4/(n+2)}
+ C_2 \|u\|^2_{L^1}.
$$
Now you can apply Young's inequality
$$
a b \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{C_1} a^p + C(\varepsilon) b^{p'},
\qquad a,b>0,
$$
with $p = \frac{n+2}{n}$ (and $p' = \frac{n+2}{2}$).

Comment: Do you have a reference for this form of the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality? And does this hold on a bounded domain? Because I only know the inequality with $+ C_2 \|\varphi\|_{L^1(\Omega)}$ on the r.h.s.

Comment: You can see the paper by Brezis and Mironescu: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01626613/document/

Comment: @mathmatix: anyway, you can use the standard Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality with the additional term (see my edited answer).

Comment: Recall that $(A+B)^2 \leq 2(A^2 + B^2)$.